# Pub/Sub architecture

Tags: c#, multithreading, networking

I try to write a pub/sub system ( client and server side ) , where client receives regular updates ( like heartbeat, message control ) and can issue command to server ( subscribe to some source , .... ).

What would be a good way to do that? I have already a server implementing a threadpool to manage incoming client connection.

I was wondering how to handle the fact the both side of the connection can read or write data in the NetworkStream . Furthermore more of my clients will actually issue very few commands to the server ( mostly to subscribe to some data and then just get regular updates ).
I try try to use plain socket,tcpclient,tcplistner ( i ll see later about WCF )

Thx
Dave

Comment: Well, i was most interested in building my own version using plain sockets in order to get a deeper knowledge of the underlying block and architecture choice.

Answer (score 3):

Or something free, like pubsub using MSMQ and WCF.

http://dotnetslackers.com/CSharp/re-108306_Building_a_Pub_Sub_Message_Bus_with_WCF_and_MSMQ.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try [NServiceBus](http://www.nservicebus.com/), [MassTransit](http://code.google.com/p/masstransit/) or [Rhino Service Bus](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/12/17/rhino-service-bus.aspx)

There's actually some good stuff about the three of them on SO ([nServiceBus, Rhino Service Bus, MassTransit - Videos, Demos, Learning Resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012289/nservicebus-rhino-service-bus-masstransit-videos-demos-learning-resources))

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [NServiceBus](http://www.nservicebus.com/), it may fit your needs.