# nServiceBus, Rhino Service Bus, MassTransit - Videos, Demos, Learning Resources

Tags: c#, nservicebus, rhino, servicebus, masstransit

Hey people would love to hear about any resources you have or know about for nServiceBus, Rhino Service Bus and MassTransit.

- Videos?
- Blog posts?
- Books?
- Demo Projects etc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/particularsoftware) at Google Groups is a very good resource.

So far I have written three articles about nServiceBus at [ArtOfBabel.com](http://ArtOfBabel.com):

- [Open Source Integration with nServiceBus](http://artofbabel.com/specials/55-open-source-integration-with-nservicebus.html)
- [Up and Running with nServiceBus 1.9](http://artofbabel.com/specials/70-up-and-running-with-nservicebus-19.html)
- [nServiceBus: Building the Solution](http://artofbabel.com/specials/72-nservicebusbuildingthesolution.html)

A few more articles should be available soon too.

Answer (score 10):

If you are interested in masstransit you can have a look at:

[Getting Started and Documentation](http://docs.masstransit-project.com/en/latest/index.html)

[Elegant code Podcast](http://elegantcode.com/2009/03/18/code-cast-25-masstransit/)  
if you are using [structure map](http://blogs.dovetailsoftware.com/blogs/kmiller/archive/2009/08/26/producing-and-consuming-messages-using-masstransit-and-structuremap.aspx)

[Dru Sellers Blog](http://codebetter.com/drusellers/) 
[Chris Patterson Blog](http://blog.phatboyg.com/)
[Their Google Groups](http://groups.google.com/group/masstransit-discuss/)

at some point you'll get to 
http://codebetter.com/blogs/dru.sellers/archive/2009/01/11/topshelf.aspx

Hope it helps

Answer (score 4):

Both [Udi Dahan](http://www.udidahan.com/category/nservicebus/) and [Andreas Öhlund](http://andreasohlund.blogspot.com/search/label/NServiceBus) blog alot about NServiceBus

Also, try the Twitter hash tag [#NServiceBus](http://twitter.com/#search?q=%23nservicebus)

Twitterers:

http://twitter.com/UdiDahan

http://twitter.com/andreasohlund

http://twitter.com/justinramel

http://twitter.com/mattburton

Answer (score 2):

Some technical sessions (video) by  Udi Dahan related to SOA and NServiceBus:

- [Udi Dahan on NServiceBus @ Bergen
  .NET User Group](http://blog.torresdal.net/2010/06/08/NNUGPresentationUdiDahanOnNServiceBus.aspx)
- [Udi Dahan on CQRS, DDD and
  NServiceBus](http://www.infoq.com/interviews/dahan-cqrs-ddd-nservicebus)

Not 100% relevant but worth watching but something which goes hand in hand:

- [DDD eXchange 2010: Udi Dahan on Architectural Innovation: CQRS](http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/design-architecture/architectural-innovation-cqrs/zx-486)

Answer (score 0):

The NServiceBus documentation is a great resource to get started with NSB.  This covers the basics of getting started and walks you through the sample projects that come with NSB before moving on to cover the main topics you will need to use NSB in production.  This must be read by anyone starting out with NSB!  You can find it here:

http://docs.particular.net/

There are official NServiceBus commercial training courses available in locations across the world.  You can also arrange for custom on-site courses or follow the official on-line training videos.  There are details on the NSB site at the link below or on on Udi Dahan's blog [here](http://www.udidahan.com/training/).

http://particular.net/onsite-training

Udi has also made  videos of the Advanced Distributed Design commercial courses available.  Whilst not specifically NSB, this is closely related and you can buy the videos [here](https://www.flickrocket.com/eshop/Catalog2.aspx?CID=2956&Theme=32&SessionID=017ff3c1-44ca-4676-87cb-6df750c39a47) or follow the link from [this blog article](http://www.udidahan.com/2011/11/10/training-us-europe-and-now-virtual/).