# I want to execute a code in c# whenever a new row is inserted in the database

Tags: c#, database, events, insert, ajax-polling

i am working on a chat application where the chat message from one client gets into the database and the other clients poll every 5 secs (using a timer) whether there is any new message or not, if yes, the messages are fetched and displayed. But this creates a problem when one user is on a slower and connection and the other one is on a very fast one. I want to develop a mechanism where a method gets executed just when a new row is inserted in the database so that the need for polling does not remain. The users will fetch the msgs only when a new chat message enters into the database by any of the clients, otherwise all remain idle. Any help would be highly appreciated. I am using asp.net and C#.

Comment: The answer to this depends a lot on the architecture of the application. Could you be more specific about this. I see one of the tags specified is ajax-polling, is this a browser based asp.net application? or is it windows clients all communicating with some form of wcf service?

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing is moving from a polling model to a publish/subscribe model (which as you can appreciate is a much better way to do chats/feeds than polling).  Two possible resources are this article [Publish/Subscribe design pattern implementation in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/SocketBasedPubSub.aspx) and this previous stack overflow question about [Pub/Sub architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974683/pub-sub-architecture).

Answer (score 1):

I'll stay away from commenting on different methods of implementing your application and concentrate on answering the question you asked - you can accomplish this using [Query Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175110.aspx).  There is a lot you can do with these, but the basic premise is that once you have set this up, you give SQL server a query you are interested in, and it will notify your application when the results change.

There's a reasonable tutorial (the code is in VB.NET, but it doesn't really change much) [here](http://code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?quickid=0605061).